# Printing Canvas of WPF aplication to file or stream without user input

Tags: wpf

I am searching for a way to create PDF document which contains canvas created in application and pass it to PDF Viewer. I know that i can print Canvas using PringDialog PrintVisual method - and this works perfectly except I want to create a file and using PrintDialog I can't get rid of dialog which asks for file name.

So far I tried PrintDialog and if there is a way to create just file without prompting user for input - that would be great beacuse pdf printed by PrintDialog also have selectable text.
I also found out some suggestions about PrintDocument class but as far as I know the quality is not so great but i just roughtly checked it and if someone know it can be achived with PrintDocument please tell.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Does someone know about name/library/article/something that will guide me to achive something that can provide me with:

- possibility to create pdf in runtime or abiliti to save it to file
- good quality

Thank you!

UPDATE: I think I will try printing to XPS and the to PDF. If this will work I will write it down here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so i have found this was most convenient. I use code from this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/536919f0-f9c5-4431-939d-5e76657c9a5d/save-canvas-element-to-xamlxps-file?forum=wpf
And now i'm converting it to pdf using syncfusion library (which my company got) https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/9077/how-to-convert-xps-to-pdf-in-c-vb-net
but i think it also can be done with pdfSharp.

PDF can be viewed in viewer, it is of good quality and if there is text, it's selectable.

```
    private async Task PrintingStreamToViewer(Canvas canvas, string pageName)//, PrintDialog prnt)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            string basename = Path.GetFileName($"temp{DateTime.Now.Second}.xps");
            string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetTempPath());

            var uri = new Uri($"{directory}\\{basename}", UriKind.Absolute);

            Export(uri, canvas);
            XPSToPdfConverter converter = new XPSToPdfConverter();
            //Convert the XPS to PDF
            PdfDocument document = converter.Convert(uri.AbsolutePath);

            var pdfPath = new Uri($"{directory}\\{pageName}{DateTime.Now.Ticks}.pdf", UriKind.Absolute);
            //Save the document
            document.Save(pdfPath.AbsolutePath);
            //Close the document
            document.Close(true);

            var pdfViewModel = PresentationInstances.Container.Resolve<PdfViewerControlViewModel>();
            try
            {
                pdfViewModel.SetPdfFile(pdfPath, (int)canvas.Width, (int)canvas.Height);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                PresHelper.WriteToDebug(e);
            }
            await _starMainPage.DialogService.ShowContentDialogAsync<IPdfViewerControl>(pdfViewModel);
        }
    }
```

Export method from link I provided above:

```
    public void Export(Uri path, FrameworkElement surface)
    {
        if (path == null) return;

        // Save current canvas transorm
        Transform transform = surface.LayoutTransform;
        // Temporarily reset the layout transform before saving
        surface.LayoutTransform = null;
        // Get the size of the canvas
        Size size = new Size(surface.Width, surface.Height);
        // Measure and arrange elements
        surface.Measure(size);
        surface.Arrange(new Rect(size));
        // Open new package
        Package package = Package.Open(path.LocalPath, FileMode.Create);
        // Create new xps document based on the package opened
        XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(package);
        // Create an instance of XpsDocumentWriter for the document
        XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
        // Write the canvas (as Visual) to the document
        writer.Write(surface);
        // Close document
        doc.Close();
        // Close package
        package.Close();
        // Restore previously saved layout
        surface.LayoutTransform = transform;
    }
```